# Magento 2 - How to disable wishlist and product review module

Tags: magento2, module, wishlist

I want to disable the Wishlist and Product Reviews module including hiding all links in the menues (i.e. Dashboard, Top Navigation).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: bin/magento module:disable moduleName cli command is disable module.

Comment: It's an old thread but here is the Magento answer: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see, deactivate the module is not a good idea. So I decided to remove all links with the default.xml.

Comment: Why it "is not a good idea" deactivate the module?

Comment: other modules may depend on it

Comment: How you remove absolutely all links? I know how to remove customer tab "My wish list" but what about on catalog "add to wish list" and so others, I feel I'll forget something if I go for this way.

Comment: How did you do that?

Answer (score 10):

To disable the module you can perform following command as @KAndy suggested

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Review
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Wishlist
```

But you can not disable these module using CLI command because other modules are depends on these two modules. You can go  `app\etc` and make relevant module to ZERO and run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

To check module status:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

It will disable frontend functionality only while admin functionality will remain same.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: The first command has a spelling mistake it should be php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Review please edit @bhupendra-jadeja

Comment: @JoelDavey oops!...Thanx...

Comment: @BhupendraJadeja This is awesome bro, + 1 from me.

Comment: Is it safe to deactivate Wishlist this way? As Magento_Customer depends on it, we could come into trouble, right?

Comment: Down-voting as this is not possible in 2.2.0, this can be achieved by disabling the module from within the admin area - please see my answer for more details.

Comment: Disabling from the admin area still leaves the wishlist block on the product pages.

Answer (score 10):

For **Magento_Wishlist**, we can also disable the feature in the admin (Store > Config > Customer > Wish List > General Options, config path is wishlist/general/active).

Regarding **Magento_Review**, the problem is that **Magento_Customer** and **Magento_Review** modules requires each others in their composer.json files and there is probably (or just maybe) a good reason for that.

According to the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html#instgde-cli-subcommands-enable-modules), disabling the module with force option (which is basically the same as disabling it directly in config.php file) *can disable your Magento store and cause problems accessing the Magento Admin*.

It **looks** fine on my project but any idea why Magento_Customer requires Magento_Review?

Answer (score 7):

As highlighted in a previous comment, disabling the module is not a good method as others may depend on it, this has been enforced in Magento 2.2.0  when trying to run the below commans:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Wishlist
```

You will receive a wall of red error messages starting with:

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_Wishlist because modules depend on it:
```

You can however, disable the module from within the admin area:

**Stores > Configuration > Customers > Wish List > Enabled : No**

Answer (score 0):

Following is the complete and proper guide to disable / enable any module in Magento 2:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html