# Magento 2 Can I disable Magento_Tax module?

Tags: magento2, tax

Tax is useless for my shop. Can I disable/remove the Magento_Tax module? If yes, how can I disable/remove it? Thanks.

Comment: refer this link for disable module http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95356/magento-2-how-to-disable-wishlist-and-product-review-module

Comment: so many magento modules depend on it. I can't disable it by using module:disable command

Answer (score 0):

You can disable in admin:
Store --> Configuration --> Advanced --> Magento_Tax: Disable
[image]

Comment: Which Magento version is this screenshot?